# Windows CE 4.0 with Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-ce, windows-server-2012, rdp

In my company, we have upgraded the Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 and we have some thin clients with an old version of RDP and they can't connect to the Server 2012 because when I does, I get this message: Because of a security error, the client could not connect to the remote computer. Verify that you are logged on to the network, and then try connecting again.

Our thin clients are: Compaq Evo T30 and a Neoware CA19 and they have Windows CE 4.0 installed by default.

Searching in internet, I've found this tutorial: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2014/03/12/windows-server-2012-rds-and-windows-mobile-connection-error/ but I can't apply it to our server because we don't want to have less security.

I've searched everything on internet to configure the Windows CE to be able to connect to our server 2012 but I can't find anything helpful :( Seriously, we don't want to apply the steps of the previous tutorial, we prefer buying new Thin Clients instead of doing that, but it will be better if there is a way to be able to connect to the server 2012 without changing anything in the server.

Anyone can help me? Please, it's very important.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a way to update your clients to a newer release of Windows CE that support new RDP versions (you should test that first) probably replacing them is the only option.